# Underline table row but not content in it

Tags: css

I want to see effect like on screenshot below:
[image]

This is my code is at the moment:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I can't figure out how not to underline content of TD but blank space only.

Comment: I would probably pull out flexbox  for this, if you could use something like that

Comment: Hard to help without a reproducible example. Consider posting the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use flexbox for this, if that is ok with your browser compatibility.

```
<html>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="holder">
        <div class="label">FooBar</div>
        <div class="divider">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="money">$1,000</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="holder">
        <div class="label">FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar</div>
        <div class="divider">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="money">$1,000</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

style:

```
.divider {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;  
}



.holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: stretch;

}

.label, .money {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pkyv8n5o/1/

[image]

Comment: may be able to skip the wrapping div and apply the class to the td.